# React component function call only updates one component instance

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component called **RightTab** like this

```
const RightTab = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="RightTab flex__container " onClick={data.onClick}>
      <img src={data.icon} alt="Dashboard Icon" />
      <p className="p__poppins">{data.name}</p>
      {data.dropDown === true ? (
        <div className="dropdown__icon">
          <img src={Assets.Arrow} alt="Arrow" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="nothing"></div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RightTab;
```

The tab has an **active state** in its CSS like this

```
.RightTab.active {
  background-color: var(--primaryGreen);
}
```

as you have seen it changes the color when an active class is added. I have an array in **the parent component**  that I pass down to the child component as props. Here is the array

```
const dataArray = [
  {
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: Assets.Dashboard,
    dropDown: false,
    onClick: handleDashBoardClick,
  },
  {
    name: "Inventory",
    icon: Assets.Inventory,
    dropDown: true,
    onClick: handleInventoryClick,
  },
  {
    name: "Reports",
    icon: Assets.Reports,
    dropDown: true,
    onClick: handleReportsClick,
  },
];
```

Here is how I pass the props down.

```
  <RightTab data={dataArray[0]} />
  <RightTab data={dataArray[1]} />
  <RightTab data={dataArray[2]} />
```

The **data** prop passed into the component is an object containing a function call as one of its properties like this. I have an **onclick attribute** on the child components' main container that is supposed to call the respective function.

The function is what **adds the active class** to make the background change color. However each time I click on the component **it only changes the background of the first occurrence**. And as you may have noticed I call the component thrice. No matter which component I click **only the first ones background changes**.

Here is an example of the function that is on the prop object.

```
const handleDashBoardClick = () => {
  const element = document.querySelector(".RightTab");
  element.classList.toggle("active");
};
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. What other approach can I use?

Comment: `const element = document.querySelector(".RightTab");` this returns the first element on the page matching ".RightTab" - it will never return the second or third such element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you use the component 3 times, it doesn't mean that a change you make in one of the components will be reflected in the other 2, unless you specifically use a state parameter that is passed to all 3 of them.

Also, the way you add the active class is not recommended since you mix react with pure js to handle the CSS class names.

I would recommend having a single click handler that toggles the active class for all `n` `RightTab` components:

```
const MainComponent = () => {
  const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState([]);
  
  const handleClick = (name) => 
  {
    const toggledActiveClass = classNames.indexOf('active') === -1
      ? classNames.concat(['active'])
      : classNames.filter((className) => className !== 'active');
      
    setClassNames(toggledActiveClass);
    
    switch (name) {
      case 'Dashboard';
        // do something
        break;
        
        case 'Inventory':
        // ....
        break;
    }
  }
  
  const dataArray = [
    {
      name: "Dashboard",
      icon: Assets.Dashboard,
      dropDown: false,
      onClick: handleClick.bind(null, 'Dashboard'),
    },
    {
      name: "Inventory",
      icon: Assets.Inventory,
      dropDown: true,
      onClick: handleClick.bind(null, 'Inventory'),
    },
    {
      name: "Reports",
      icon: Assets.Reports,
      dropDown: true,
      onClick: handleClick.bind(null, 'Reports'),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {dataArray.map((data) => 
        <RightTab key={data.name} 
                  data={data} 
                  classNames={classNames} />)}
    </>
  );
};

const RightTab = ({ data, classNames }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classNames.concat(['RightTab flex__container']).join(' ')} 
         onClick={data.onClick}>
      <img src={data.icon} alt="Dashboard Icon" />
      <p className="p__poppins">{data.name}</p>
      {data.dropDown === true ? (
        <div className="dropdown__icon">
          <img src={Assets.Arrow} alt="Arrow" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="nothing"></div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Wow. This just worked. Thanks Mahn